What if I clean cache on safari ? Passkey
What should be if I create passkey on apple device on safari with webauthn navigator.credentials.create(). Then I see a one passkey on device. If I clear cache in safari and try again. It force me to create another passkey again. And after that i Have two passkeys on device. Should be like this ?why?
I tried to log with passkey after I clear the safari cache on apple device

Does this information possibly help?

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
